# How do you use the iPhone Reachability Notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, reachability

I have the following code:

```
- (void) testInternetConnection {
internetConnection = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

// Internet is reachable
internetConnection.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Update the UI on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");
    });
};

// Internet is not reachable
internetConnection.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Update the UI on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Someone broke the internet :(");
    });
};

[internetConnection startNotifier];
}
```

How do I tell if my internet has changed using the notifier? I understand the singleton method and use that when needed.

Comment: yes i am using that answer, but how do I check once the notifier is started?

Comment: using kReachabilityChangedNotification

Comment: and this is always true even when I turn the network off: BOOL status = ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable);

Comment: ensure BOOL status = ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable) , on device if you are testing in simulator

Comment: +lots to Alok, i didn't realize the simulator connectivity dealt witht hte device too

Answer (score 2):

try to test your code on device when ever possible.

ensure

```
BOOL status = ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable)
```

, on device if you are testing in simulator

The simulator just uses your default Mac network connection so you need to disconnect your mac from the network and the simulator will experience the same loss of network connectivity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can check reachability by this code,

//to make reachability object

```
reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
```

//start notifier

```
[reachability startNotifier];
```

//get reachability status

```
remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //First import Reachability classes
// In Appdelegate .h file create variables
  Reachability *hostReach,*internetReach,*wifiReach;
  Reachability *internetReachable;

// After that add this code didfinish lonching with options
 internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] ;
 [internetReachable startNotifier];

 -(BOOL) connectedToNetwork
 {
const char *host_name = "www.google.com";
BOOL _isDataSourceAvailable = NO;
Boolean success;
SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL,host_name);
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
_isDataSourceAvailable = success &&
(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) &&
!(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);

CFRelease(reachability);

return _isDataSourceAvailable;
 }
```